# Why my react code dont show pokemon name?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im new in react development and i dont understand why this code dont show `pokemon.name` on the first h1 tag:

```
import './Container.css';

function Container ({ id }) {

const getPokemon = async(id) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    return await res.json();
}
            
const pokemon = getPokemon(id);

return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
);
}

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `getPokemon` returns a *Promise*, not data.  And that `Promise` is never awaited.

---

**More specific to React in your case, however...**

You don't want to try to await and return the value, you want to make use of *state* in React.

Declare a state value at the start of your component:

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});
```

Update it in your asynchronous operation:

```
const res = await fetch(url);
setPokemon(await res.json());
```

Invoke your operation when the component first loads (or any time `id` changes):

```
useEffect(() => {
  getPokemon(id);
}, [id]);
```

Then you'll find that the component first renders with no data, then re-renders after the AJAX operation so it can use the new data.  Updating state triggers a React component to re-render.